# Search Box to retrieve data using Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Below is the **index page:** having these code: Data gets populated in a div as expected.

```
   <h2>Search for users</h2>
             <input type="text" name="search" id="search" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter Customer ID here....">
             <div id="output"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#search").keyup(function(){
          var query = $(this).val();
          if (query != "") {
            $.ajax({
              url: 'ajax-db-search.php',
              method: 'POST',
              data: {query:query},
              success: function(data){
 
                $('#output').html(data);
                $('#output').css('display', 'block');
                $("#search").focusin(function(){
                    $('#output').css('display', 'block');
                });
              }
            });
          } else {
          $('#output').css('display', 'none');
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

This is the **ajax-db-search.php** page. (In the IF tags I tried it with == and no good luck yet.)

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("*****","*********","******","*****");
 

     
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `create_customer` WHERE `Customer Id` LIKE '{$_POST['query']}%' LIMIT 6";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $plan = $query['Plan'];
    
    
  if ($plan = "planA") {
      
     while ($user = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     
      echo "<h2>".$user['Customer Name']."</h2>";
      
      echo "<h4><a href='http://smjw.phatake.in/admin/cc.php?recordID=".$user['id']."'>Update Profile Details</a></h4>";
      
      echo "<h4><a href='http://smjw.phatake.in/admin/planA_details.php?recordID=".$user['Customer Id']."'>Receive Payment</a></h4>";
    var_dump ($plan);
     }
  
  }
     
      if ($plan = "planB") {
     while ($user = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     
      echo "<h2>".$user['Customer Name']."</h2>";
      
      echo "<h4><a href='http://smjw.phatake.in/admin/cc.php?recordID=".$user['id']."'>Update Profile Details</a></h4>";
      
    
      echo "<h4><a href='http://smjw.phatake.in/admin/planB_details.php?recordID=".$user['Customer Id']."'>Receive Payment</a></h4>";
      
     }
      }
    
    
          if ($plan = "planC") {
     while ($user = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     
      echo "<h2>".$user['Customer Name']."</h2>";
      
      echo "<h4><a href='http://smjw.phatake.in/admin/cc.php?recordID=".$user['id']."'>Update Profile Details</a></h4>";
      
    
      echo "<h4><a href='http://smjw.phatake.in/admin/planC_details.php?recordID=".$user['Customer Id']."'>Receive Payment</a></h4>";
      
     } 
          }
     
     
               if ($plan = "planA1") {
     while ($user = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     
      echo "<h2>".$user['Customer Name']."</h2>";
      
      echo "<h4><a href='http://smjw.phatake.in/admin/cc.php?recordID=".$user['id']."'>Update Profile Details</a></h4>";
      
    
      echo "<h4><a href='http://smjw.phatake.in/admin/planA1_details.php?recordID=".$user['Customer Id']."'>Receive Payment</a></h4>";
      
     } 
               
     
     
               }

     
   else {
    echo "<p style='color:red'>User not found...</p>";
  }
 

?>
```

The Problem is with the If condition: The Url's that needs to be displayed on my index page should change according to the $plan variable. But for some reason the $plan variable is always planA..

There are 4/5 Plans.. planA, planB, planc, planA1 each having different Urls that needs to displayed.

The URL do get populated but will be always the First IF conditions URL for all the customers.

Please help me out with this. Stuck for big time.

-------Update-------------

[image]

I want each of the Receive Payment to be according to the if conditions.. Now its all only planA

Comment: A single `=` assigns a value, and in your code the result is assessed as a boolean result - `true`. At the very least you should be using `==` in those conditions.

Comment: You're not fetching the result of your query after you execute it. You're simply assigning a value of an element in the `$query` array, but at that point that variable is a string. You've probably got a server error log full of PHP warnings and errors. Find the error log, fix all the errors you see there, ask again if your code is still not working as it should.

Comment: I have tried using ==. but always goes for last else condition @TangentiallyPerpendicular

Comment: As I have already indicated, there are other problems with your code too.

Comment: Please have a loot @ the Image in the updated section @TangentiallyPerpendicular

Answer (score 0):

Hmm you said you tried `==` it should be `==` and not `=`.

Firstly please note your sql queries any kind of query should be prepare statements even if you trust your users.

Now please note that:

```php
echo "planA"=="plana" ? "yes" : "no"; // Output no. Have you tried this?
```

Edit: I overlooked " But for some reason the $plan variable is always planA.." that is because of `=` in your ifs

```php
$plan = "";
if ($plan = "a") {
    echo $plan;
}
if ($plan = "b") {
    echo $plan;
}
if ($plan = "c") {
    echo $plan;
}
//output: abc
```

Lastly, please use else if, you don't need to check if 3 times it can only be 1 option.

Edit 2: I think you have some way to go. Please have look at the code below.
Here is the complete working with your bug I think:

```php
<?php
    // Since I have no post i will set it by default
    $_POST['query'] = 'AZ12';

    // Check for data validation...
    if (!isset($_POST['query']) || empty($_POST['query'])) return;

    // Now for query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `create_customer` WHERE `Customer Id` LIKE ? LIMIT 6";

    // Prepare the statement to insert user_answer in ? above
    // replace "s" based on your appropriate var type
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    
    // $stmt->bind_param("s", "%".$_POST['query']."%"); <-- This would yield error
    // ^ fix: Store the 2nd param first
    $like = "%{$_POST['query']}%";
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $like);
    $stmt->execute();

    // Get the results 
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    echo "<br/>";
    print_r($result);
    // Output: mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 3 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 ) 
    // ^ This will show all the elements part of $result (your case 6)

    // Why this? Because to me it seems like you have hard-coded plans
    // because if $plan = A,B,C and then you insert while loop inside the if's
    $plans = array(0 => 'PlanA', 1 => 'PlanB', 2 => 'PlanC');
    foreach($plans as $value) {
        echo "<h1>$value</h1><br/>";
        // Now loop as assoc like you have...
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            print_r($row);
            // ^ With above get the data value you need such as:
            // echo "<h2>".$row['Customer Id']."</h2>";
        }
        // Add this to fix the fetch_assoc
        $result->data_seek(0); // without this you will see the image below
    }

    // ^ Output Notice we only show plan A rows!!! look image below.
    // Fix indicate by $result->data_seek(0);

?>
```

I am assuming this is what you get: ["Why only A show?"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7xlw.png)

Comment: $plan is always planA only. It never changes. It is not looping through @ziaahsan.

Comment: @DoorsShelters You have typos in your code. Please review and edit code again. Such as: $query = "SELECT * FROM create_customer WHERE..."; and then $plan = $query['Plan']; but $query is  a string being accessed as an array?

Comment: @DoorsShelters Please see edit 2. I have made changes to my post. That should clear things up perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Here i am using `php pdo` for perform the search task.

i am create a two file 'search.php' is a send ajax request to `query.php` file.

search.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Search</title>
    <!-- jQuery cdn link -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search">

    <div class="table-div" style="display: none"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        $.get("/query.php", {data:$(this).val()}, function(data, status){
            let row = JSON.parse(data);
            let table = "";

            table += "<table>";
                table += "<thead>";
                    table += "<tr>";
                        table += "<th>Customer name</th><th>Customer salary</th>";
                    table += "</tr>";
                table += "</thead>";
                table += "<tbody>";
                    if(row.data != "No data found") {
                        $.each(row.data, function(key, value){
                            table += "<tr>";
                                table += "<td>"+ value.customer_name +"</td>";
                                table += "<td>"+ value.cust_sal +"</td>";
                            table += "</tr>";
                        });
                    }
                table += "</tbody>";
            table += "</table>";

            $(".table-div").html(table);
            $(".table-div").show();
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

query.php

```
<?php

    // This is a database connectivity
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=test;", 'root', '');

    if(isset($_GET['data']))
    {
        $query = "%".$_GET['data']."%";
        $searchSQL = "SELECT * FROM cust WHERE customer_name LIKE :cname";
        $searchState = $conn->prepare($searchSQL);
        $searchState->bindParam(":cname", $query);

        if($searchState->execute())
        {
            if($searchState->rowCount() > 0)
            {
                $data = $searchState->fetchAll();
            }
            else
            {
                $data = "No data found";
            }
        }

        echo json_encode(["data" => $data]);
    }

?>
```